# Ubuntu 14 upgrade fatal error

Tags: upgrade

When I tried to upgrade to Ubuntu 14 from 13, I received a fatal error.  It was opening and installing the files, but said gnome had a problem and something about a directory couldn't be found or opened.  The install froze, so I rebooted the machine. Now all I get is the Ubuntu screen, then it says I will be running in a lowered display until I reset it manually, then the screen says What do you want to do.

I also have Ubuntu 10 and 11 on disk, but when I reboot with them in the computer it reads them, but does nothing.

I would like to keep all my settings and installed software if possible.  Any idea what I need to do to fix this?  Thank you

Comment: man you need to backup your data, and reinstall the desired version.
all the best

Comment: I only need my Firefox Bookmarks stored on the machine.  Do you know what I need to do to get it.  I can only get as far as a screen that says "What do you want to do?"  I don't know what to input or bypass it.  Thank you.

Comment: there is an option in firefox where you can make an account on firefox, and you can save your all bookmarks.:) and when you log on in any other pc, you just log on to firefox and your all saved bookmarks will appear on that pc or smartphone.